# How to do live streaming from iOS device with wowza server

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, wowza

I have integrate Wowza with my server and its running. Now I want to stream live video/audio to iOS device from another iOS device with this server.
I google but there is no information how can do this thing.
Can anyone provide me the steps to do that? I tried almost all stack overflow questions regarding this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer here: [video streaming from iOS camera to wowza](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42943745/553071)

Comment: Thanks Rajender, but I had successfully delivered this project in May 2015 with all these functionalities.